# ML.NET Timeseries ForecastBySsa hoirzon: 7 How to know how many time in the future is the first prediction?

Tags: c#, time-series, forecasting, ml.net, forecast

I Use for my forecasting prediction Timeseries mlContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySSA.

Now I want to know from which time the next prediction is.

When I use:

```
     var forecastingPipeline = mlContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySsa(
            outputColumnName: "ForecastedFillLevel",
            inputColumnName: "FillLevel",
            windowSize: 7,
            seriesLength: 30,
            trainSize: 100,
            horizon: 7,
            confidenceLevel: 0.95f,
            confidenceLowerBoundColumn: "LowerBoundFillLevel",
            confidenceUpperBoundColumn: "UpperBoundFillLevel");
```

It will predict 7 values in the future, but I wanna know which DateTime in the future the prediction is based on.

In my dataset the difference of data in one day difference from 4-10 data rows in a day.

Now I use this code.

```
 static void Forecast(IDataView testData, int horizon, TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> forecaster, MLContext mlContext)
    {

        ModelOutput forecast = forecaster.Predict();




        IEnumerable<string> forecastOutput =
            mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ModelInput>(testData, reuseRowObject: false)
                .Take(horizon)
                .Select((ModelInput Message, int index) =>
                {
                    string rentalDate = Message.DateTime.ToShortDateString();
                    //float actualRentals = rental.FillLevel;
                    float lowerEstimate = Math.Max(0, forecast.LowerBoundFillLevel[index]);
                    float estimate = forecast.ForecastedFillLevel[index];
                    float upperEstimate = forecast.UpperBoundFillLevel[index];
                    return $"Date: {rentalDate}\n" +
                   // $"Actual Rentals: {actualRentals}\n" +
                    $"Lower Estimate: {lowerEstimate}\n" +
                    $"Forecast: {estimate}\n" +
                    $"Upper Estimate: {upperEstimate}\n";
                });

        // Output predictions
        Console.WriteLine("Rental Forecast");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
        foreach (var prediction in forecastOutput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prediction);
        }

       
       
    }
```

But the DateTime that gets printed are the first 7 datetime values in my dataset. The prediction values are good and based on the last datarows.

So my question is how can I print the correct DateTime values for the prediction